# How to pass whole Row to UDF - Spark DataFrame filter

Tags: apache-spark

I'm writing filter function for complex JSON dataset with lot's of inner structures. Passing individual columns is too cumbersome.

So I declared the following UDF:

```
val records:DataFrame = = sqlContext.jsonFile("...")
def myFilterFunction(r:Row):Boolean=???
sqlc.udf.register("myFilter", (r:Row)=>myFilterFunction(r))
```

Intuitively I'm thinking it will work like this:

```
records.filter("myFilter(*)=true")
```

What is the actual syntax?

Comment: Could you specify your filter function a bit more? Using `Row` throws away a lot of optimizations a `DataFrame` does for you.

Comment: The filter is pretty complex. The structure of the record is several Map fields with bunch of key-value pairs in them

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to use `struct()` function for constructing the row while making a call to the function, follow these steps.

Import Row,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
```

Define the UDF

```
def myFilterFunction(r:Row) = {r.get(0)==r.get(1)}
```

Register the UDF

```
sqlContext.udf.register("myFilterFunction", myFilterFunction _)
```

Create the dataFrame

```
val records = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(("sachin", "sachin"), ("aggarwal", "aggarwal1"))).toDF("text", "text2")
```

Use the UDF

```
records.filter(callUdf("myFilterFunction",struct($"text",$"text2"))).show
```

When u want all columns to be passed to UDF.

```
records.filter(callUdf("myFilterFunction",struct(records.columns.map(records(_)) : _*))).show
```

Result:

```
+------+------+
|  text| text2|
+------+------+
|sachin|sachin|
+------+------+
```

Comment: That helps. Not 100% what I needed, but better then an alternative.

Comment: please elaborate what I missed to make it 100%, I will try to update my suggestion as per ur requirement.

Comment: the ideal would be not having to list columns, but somehow referring to the whole row.

Comment: (very late on this, I'm sure you have the answer now but: `struct(df.columns.map(df(_)) : _*)`

Comment: Will this approach work when columns are more than 150?

Comment: I could edit it, but I only got it to work with     import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF.  I note it is callUDF. May be things have changed ober the years.

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> inputDF
res40: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [email: string, first_name: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> inputDF.printSchema
root
 |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- last_name: string (nullable = true)
```

Now, I would like to filter the rows based on the Gender Field. I can accomplish that by using the `.filter($"gender" === "Male")` but I would like to do with the `.filter(function)`.

So, defined my anonymous functions

```
val isMaleRow = (r:Row) => {r.getAs("gender") == "Male"}

val isFemaleRow = (r:Row) => { r.getAs("gender") == "Female" }

inputDF.filter(isMaleRow).show()

inputDF.filter(isFemaleRow).show()
```

I felt the requirement can be done in a better way i.e without declaring as UDF and invoke it.

Comment: Can you remove the non-code explanations from the formatting?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the first answer. When we want all columns to be passed to UDF we can use

```
 struct("*")
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take an action over the whole row and process it in a distributed way, take the row in the DataFrame and send to a function as a struct and then convert to a dictionary to execute the specific action, is very important to execute the collect method over the final DataFrame because Spark has the `LazyLoad` activated and don't work with full data at less you tell it explicitly.

In my case I should send the row of a DataFrame to index as Dictionary object:

1. Import libraries.
2. Declare the `udf` and the lambda must receiving the row structure.
3. Execute specific function, in this case send to index a dictionary (the row structure converted to a dict).
4. The DataFrame origin execute a `withColum` method that indicates to Spark execute this in each row, before make the call to collect, this allows to execute the function in a distribuible way. Don't forget send to a other DataFrame Variable.
5. Execute the `collect` method to execute the process and distribute the function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

myUdf = udf(lambda row: sendToES(row.asDict()), IntegerType())
dfWithControlCol = df.withColumn("control_col", myUdf(struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])))
dfWithControlCol.collect()
```

Comment: can u give a scala example?