# How Java code register none parameter UDF with Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, udf

I have set of APIs so can define different UDF to use. Such as:

```html
import scala.Function0;
class UDF0 {
 private String targetField;
 private Function0 function0;
}

import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0;
udf0.setFunction0(new AbstractFunction0<String>() {
  @Override
  public String apply() {
   return "IA";
  }
 })

class UDF0Parser implement Parser<UDF0> {
 public void parse(UDF0 udf0) {
  String udfName = "udf0";
  getSparkSession().udf().register(udfName, ()-> udf0.getFunction0().apply(), ???);
  Column col = functions.callUDF(udfName);
  getDateSet().withColumn("newCol", col);
 }
}
```

- Question1

How can I get the scala String TypeTag (position ???, third parameter) in Java?

I turn to write UDF0Parser using scala:

```html
class UDF0Parser implement Parser<UDF0> {
 def parse(udf0: UDF0): Unit = {
  val udfName = "udf0"
  getSparkSession.udf.register(udfName, udf0.getFunction0)
  val col = functions.callUDF(udfName)
  getDateSet.withColumn("new", col)
 }
}
```

But I got a runtime error:

```html
Error:(14, 65) type mismatch;
 found   : Function0
 required: () => ?
    stepContext.getSparkSession.udf.register(udfName, transform.getFunction0);
                                                                ^
```

- Question2

Isn't ()->xxx just a instance of Function0? What should I do?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself, passing whole row as parameter to UDF, not need to write UDF for one or more columns.
See: [How to pass whole Row to UDF - Spark DataFrame filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816975/how-to-pass-whole-row-to-udf-spark-dataframe-filter)