# How can I use the literal value of a spark dataframe column?

Tags: apache-spark

I have this simple dataframe that looks like this,

```
+---+---+---+---+
|nm | ca| cb| cc|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|123|  0|  0|
|  b|  1|  2|  3|
|  c|  0|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

What I want to do is,

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|nm |ca |cb |cc |p  |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|a  |123|0  |0  |1  |
|b  |1  |2  |3  |1  |
|c  |0  |1  |0  |0  |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

bascially added a new column `p`, such that, if value of column `nm` is 'a', check column `ca` is >0, if yes put '1' for column p1 else 0.

My code,

```
        def purchaseCol: UserDefinedFunction =
    udf((brand: String) => s"c$brand")

val a = ss.createDataset(List(
        ("a", 123, 0, 0),
        ("b", 1, 2, 3),
        ("c", 0, 1, 0)))
    .toDF("nm", "ca", "cb", "cc")

a.show()
a.withColumn("p", when(lit(DataFrameUtils.purchaseCol($"nm")) > 0, 1).otherwise(0))
.show(false)
```

It doesnt seem to be working and is returning 0 for all rows in col 'p'.

PS: Columns number is over 100 and they are dynamically generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map over `rdd`, calculate and add `p` to each row:

```
val a = sc.parallelize(
    List(("a", 123, 0, 0),
         ("b", 1, 2, 3),
         ("c", 0, 1, 0))
).toDF("nm", "ca", "cb", "cc")

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val b = a.rdd.map(r => {
    val s = r.getAs[String]("nm")
    val v = r.getAs[Int](s"c$s")
    val p = if(v > 0) 1 else 0
    Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq :+ p)
})

val new_schema = StructType(a.schema :+ StructField("p", IntegerType, true))

val df_new = spark.createDataFrame(b, new_schema)

df_new.show
+---+---+---+---+---+
| nm| ca| cb| cc|  p|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|123|  0|  0|  1|
|  b|  1|  2|  3|  1|
|  c|  0|  1|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: ya this is what i did for the most part, didn't really wanna use rdds and reconstruct dataframe. was looking for more elegant solution, but wth, +1

Answer (score 0):

looking at your logic

> > if value of column nm is 'a', check column ca is >0, if yes put '1' for column p1 else 0.

you can simply do

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
a.withColumn("p", when((col("nm") === lit("a")) && (col("ca") > 0), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)))
```

but looking at your output `dataframe`, you would require an `||` instead of `&&`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
a.withColumn("p", when((col("nm") === lit("a")) || (col("ca") > 0), lit(1)).otherwise(lit(0)))
```

Comment: the challenge is to do it programattically, a is a part of ca, b is a part of cb etc..

Answer (score 0):

If "c*" columns number is limited, UDF with all values can be used:

```
  val nameMatcherFunct = (nm: String, ca: Int, cb: Int, cc: Int) => {
  val value = nm match {
    case "a" => ca
    case "b" => cb
    case "c" => cc
  }
  if (value > 0) 1 else 0
}

def purchaseValueUDF = udf(nameMatcherFunct)

val result = a.withColumn("p", purchaseValueUDF(col("nm"), col("ca"), col("cb"), col("cc")))
```

If you have many "c*" columns, function with Row as parameter can be used:
[How to pass whole Row to UDF - Spark DataFrame filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816975/how-to-pass-whole-row-to-udf-spark-dataframe-filter)

Comment: ya thats the problem, columns are dynamic

Answer (score -1):

```
val a1 = sc.parallelize(
    List(("a", 123, 0, 0),
         ("b", 1, 2, 3),
         ("c", 0, 1, 0))
).toDF("nm", "ca", "cb", "cc")

a1.show()


+---+---+---+---+
| nm| ca| cb| cc|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|123|  0|  0|
|  b|  1|  2|  3|
|  c|  0|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+


val newDf = a1.withColumn("P", when($"ca" > 0, 1).otherwise(0))
newDf.show()

+---+---+---+---+---+
| nm| ca| cb| cc|  P|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|123|  0|  0|  1|
|  b|  1|  2|  3|  1|
|  c|  0|  1|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: noe, this is just wrong, you have to consider different columns for each row. suppose if there was another column cd after cc for another row `d,1,4,5,0` the value of P corresponding to this would be 0 but you llogic would mark it as 1