# How to pass Row in UDF?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a UDF in Java.

I'd like to perform a more complex operation on the `DateSet<Row>`. For that 
I think I need to pass `DataSet<Row>` as the input to my UDF and return the output. Here is my code:

```
 UDF1<Dataset<Row>,String> myUDF = new UDF1<Dataset<Row>,String>() {
            public String call(Dataset<Row> input) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(input);
                return "test";
            }
            };

           // Register the UDF with our SQLContext
            spark.udf().register("myUDF", myUDF, DataTypes.StringType); {
```

But when i go and try to use myUDF it seems like callUDF function only accepts a `Column` not a `DataSet<Row>`.

Can anyone help how I can pass the `DataSet<Row>` as an input parameter to a UDF? Is there any other way i can call my UDF in Spark SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass whole Row to UDF - Spark DataFrame filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816975/how-to-pass-whole-row-to-udf-spark-dataframe-filter)

Comment: I checked that already That does not solve my problem. that is implemented in Scala. I am looking for something in java.

Comment: There is really not much difference. You need `struct(all columns go here)`.

Comment: @user10465355 That **may** be a solution but that changes the semantics of the question (which is to transform a Dataset).

Answer (score 0):

> But when i go and try to use myUDF it seems like callUDF function only accept the column not the Dataset, Can any one help how i can pass the dataset as input parameter in the UDF. Is there any other way i can call my UDF in Spark SQL

There are a few questions here.

First of all, a UDF is a function that work with (the values inside) `Columns`. In a sense, you could use `struct` function to combine required columns to pretend you work with an entire Dataset.

If however you want to work with an entire Dataset, you really want a pure Java/Scala method that simply accepts the Dataset. There's not much Spark can do about it. It's simply a Java/Scala programming.

There's however a very nice method that I don't see much use of, i.e. [Dataset.transform](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset):

> **transform[U](t: (Dataset[T]) ⇒ Dataset[U]): Dataset[U]** Concise syntax for chaining custom transformations.

That allows for chaining methods that accept a Dataset which makes for a very readable code (and seems exactly what you want).