# Pass row to UDF and select column based on pattern match

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I achieve the following by passing a row to a udf ?

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("col_Z", 
              when($"col_x" === "a", $"col_A")
              .when($"col_x" === "b", $"col_B")
              .when($"col_x" === "c", $"col_C")
              .when($"col_x" === "d", $"col_D")
              .when($"col_x" === "e", $"col_E")
              .when($"col_x" === "f", $"col_F")
              .when($"col_x" === "g", $"col_G")
      )
```

As I understand it, only columns can be passed as arguments to a UDF in Scala Spark.

I have taken a look at this question:

[How to pass whole Row to UDF - Spark DataFrame filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816975/how-to-pass-whole-row-to-udf-spark-dataframe-filter)

and tried to implement this udf:

```
def myUDF(r:Row) = udf {

 val z : Float = r.getAs("col_x") match {
      case "a" => r.getAs("col_A")
      case "b" => r.getAs("col_B")
      case other => lit(0.0)
   }
 z
}
```

but I'm getting a type mismatch error:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("a")
 required: Nothing
 case "a" => r.getAs("col_A")
      ^
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass whole Row to UDF - Spark DataFrame filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816975/how-to-pass-whole-row-to-udf-spark-dataframe-filter)

Comment: This is not the case