# Filtering a Dataset<Row> if month is in list of integers

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a spark Dataset of rows in Java that looks like this.

```
+-------+-------------------+---------------+----------+--------------------+-----+
|item_id|          date_time|horizon_minutes|last_value|              values|label|
+-------+-------------------+---------------+----------+--------------------+-----+
|      8|2019-04-30 09:55:00|             15|       0.0|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|  0.0|
|      8|2019-04-30 10:00:00|             15|       0.0|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|  0.0|
|      8|2019-04-30 10:05:00|             15|       0.0|[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,...|  0.0|
```

I want to filter the Dataframe to take only those rows whose month is inside a list of integers (e.g. 1,2,5,12)

I have tried the filter function based on strings

```
rowsDS.filter("month(date_time)" ???)
```

But I don't know how to include the "isin list" of integers condition.

I have also tried to filter through a lambda function with no luck.

```
rowsDS.filter(row -> listofints.contains(row.getDate(1).getMonth()))
    Evaluation failed. Reason(s):
        Lambda expressions cannot be used in an evaluation expression
```

Is there any simple way to do this?. I would preferably want to use lambda functions as I do not like much the string based filters of SparkSQL such as the first example.

Answer (score 1):

For Dataframe:

```
val result = df.where(month($"date_time").isin(2, 3, 4))
```

In Java:

```
Dataset<Row> result = df.where(month(col("date_time")).isin(2, 3, 4));
```

For get "col" and "month" function in Java:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that this is Java

Comment: testingData.where(month(testingData.col("date_time")).isin(2, 3, 4)) as you need the testingData.col part to get the column. Still, there is no month function

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$  `public static Column month(Column e)`
Extracts the month as an integer from a given date/timestamp/string.

Answer (score 0):

You can define UDF as described [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-udfs.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816975/how-to-pass-whole-row-to-udf-spark-dataframe-filter)

My example:

```
val seq1 = Seq(
  ("A", "abc", 0.1, 0.0, 0),
  ("B", "def", 0.15, 0.5, 0),
  ("C", "ghi", 0.2, 0.2, 1),
  ("D", "jkl", 1.1, 0.1, 0),
  ("E", "mno", 0.1, 0.1, 0)
)

val ls = List("A", "B")
val df1 = ss.sparkContext.makeRDD(seq1).toDF("cA", "cB", "cC", "cD", "cE")

def rawFilterFunc(r: String) =  ls.contains(r)

ss.udf.register("ff", rawFilterFunc _)

df1.filter(callUDF("ff", df1("cA"))).show()
```

Gives output:

```
+---+---+----+---+---+
| cA| cB|  cC| cD| cE|
+---+---+----+---+---+
|  A|abc| 0.1|0.0|  0|
|  B|def|0.15|0.5|  0|
+---+---+----+---+---+
```